# Erros com metodos Put e Delete - MethodNotAllowedHttpException - Laravel e Angular

Tags: angularjs, laravel

Ola, segue minha luta com angular e laravel.

Agora estou tendo problema com os metodos put e delete, não fiz nada além do que tinha antes em meu código, só estou acrescentando mais models - onde copio o código anterior e mudos os nomes.

Mas ao tentar editar ou deletar algum registro, recebo esse erro

`MethodNotAllowedHttpException` no laravel

E pelo console

> DELETE http://localhost:8000/empresas/exclui/1 500 (Internal Server Error)
>   (anonymous) @   angular.js:11881
>   sendReq @   angular.js:11642
>   serverRequest   @   angular.js:11352
>   processQueue    @   angular.js:16170
>   (anonymous) @   angular.js:16186
>   $eval   @   angular.js:17444
>   $digest @   angular.js:17257
>   $apply  @   angular.js:17552
>   (anonymous) @   angular.js:25627
>   dispatch    @   app.js:3
>   g.handle    @   app.js:3

Já tentei algumas coisas de erros parecidos que vi aqui no forum, mas nada até agora, e não sei o que poderia ser, pois meu código vinha funcionando normalmente.

Não sei onde pode estar o erro então, postarei algumas partes, caso seja necessário solicitem que incluo mais.

PS: a única diferença agora para os models anteriores é que este tem um relacionamento N/N, mas o model anterior que é 1/N também começou a dar erro.

Atenciosamente.

```
namespace confin;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Empresa extends Model
{

    public function processo()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('confin\Processo','empresa_processo');
    }


}

    class Processo extends Model {

    public function convites()

    {

        return $this->hasOne('confin\Convites');
    }


    public function empresa()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('confin\Empresa','empresa_processo');
    }

}


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
           <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Cadastro de Número de processo</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="hidden" class="form-control" ng-model="processo.ano" >
              <label>Ano:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="processo.ano">
           </div>

           <div class="form-group">
              <label>Nº. Processo:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="processo.numero">
           </div>

           <label>Descrição:</label>
           <div class="form-group">
              <textarea  class="form-control" ng-model="processo.descricao"rows="10" cols="500"></textarea>
           </div>

        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="processo = {}">Cancelar</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="salvar()">Salvar</button>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>



app.factory('processoService',function($http) {
    return {
        lista: function(){
            return $http.get('/processos/lista');
        },
        cadastra: function(data){
            return $http.post('/processos/cadastra', data);
        },
        edita: function(data){
            var id = data.id;
            delete data.id;
            return $http.put('/processos/edita/'+id, data);
        },
        exclui: function(id){
            return $http.delete('/processos/exclui/'+id)
        }
    }
});



// Controller
app.controller('processosController', function($scope, processoService, empresaService) {
    $scope.listar = function(){
        processoService.lista().success(function(data){
            $scope.processos = data;
        });

        // ordenar
        $scope.ordenar = function(keyname){
        $scope.sortKey = keyname;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
        };
    }


    $scope.editar = function(data){
        $scope.processo = data;
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }

    $scope.salvar = function(){
        alert(processo.id);
        if($scope.processo.id){
            processoService.edita($scope.processo).success(function(res){
                $scope.listar();
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            });
        }else{
            processoService.cadastra($scope.processo).success(function(res){
                $scope.listar();
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            });
        }
    }

    $scope.excluir = function(data){
        if(confirm("Tem certeza que deseja excluir?")){
            processoService.exclui(data.id).success(function(res){
                $scope.listar();
            });
        }
    }
});




namespace confin\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use DB; // para usar a classe DB

class ProcessoController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    // Index
    public function index()
    {
        return view('processo');
    }

    // Listando processo
    public function lista()
    {
        return DB::table('processos')
            ->get();
    }


    // Cadastrando Processo
    public function novo(Request $request)
    {
        $data = sizeof($_POST) > 0 ? $_POST : json_decode($request->getContent(), true); // Pega o post ou o raw

        return DB::table('processos')
            ->insertGetId($data);
    }


    // Editando processo
    public function editar($id, Request $request){
        $data = sizeof($_POST) > 0 ? $_POST : json_decode($request->getContent(), true); // Pega o post ou o raw

        $res = DB::table('processos')
            ->where('id',$id)
            ->update($data);

        return ["status" => ($res)?'ok':'erro'];
    }


    // Excluindo Processo
    public function excluir($id)
    {
        $res = DB::table('processos')
            -> where('id',$id)
            -> delete();

        return ["status" => ($res)?'ok':'erro'];
    }
}
```

DELETE    cadastro/processo/{id}       confin\Http\Controllers\ProcessoController@excluir web,auth

PUT      cadastro/processo/{id}         confin\Http\Controllers\ProcessoController@editar  web,auth

POST    cadastro/processos             confin\Http\Controllers\ProcessoController@novo   web,auth

GET|HEAD | cadastro/processos   confin\Http\Controllers\ProcessoController@lista  web,auth

Comment: Coloca na pergunta teu arquivo de rotas (acho que o que mais importa da pergunta junto ao seu processoService).

Answer (score 0):

Isso certamente é problemas com rotas.

1º - Procura no `php artisan route:list` se a rota `empresas/exclui/{id}` está definida e com método DELETE

2º - Se não estiver posta a linha Route::resource/get/post/delete do Processos do seu arquivo routes.php pra eu dar uma olhada.

Comment: Aparentemente não tem erro, pelo menos para mim, o estranho, é que se tento editar e excluir da erro, agora se eu tento excluir direto vai, e se eu editar da erro, aperto f5 e tento excluir vai. não sei se deu para entender

Comment: DELETE |cadastro/empresa/{id}    confin\Http\Controllers\EmpresaController@excluir web,auth     
 PUT|cadastro/empresa/{id}|confin\Http\Controllers\EmpresaController@editar  web,auth    
 POST|cadastro/empresas|confin\Http\Controllers\EmpresaController@novo   web,auth   
 GET|HEAD|cadastro/empresas|confin\Http\Controllers\EmpresaController@lista  web,auth

Comment: achei o erro ao trocar essa linha return Convites::with('Processo')->get(); por essa return DB::table('convites')->get(); , sei que é no relacionamento, mas não o porque.

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser a cache das rotas

```
php artisan route:cache
```

e depois pesquisa sua rota

```
php artisan route:list --name=nome_da_sua_rota
```

e ai você pode verificar com certeza se sua rota exista e esta com o método correto